# Degree 3 map from the torus to the sphere.

Tags: general-topology

Construct a degree 3 map from $T$ to $S^2$ where $T$ is the torus?

I can find a degree 0 and degree 1 map by the following proof:

Embed $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the usual way.  Consider any point $p$ not in the image of $T$.  Consider the winding map $f:T\longrightarrow S^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x-p)/|x-p|$.  If $p$ is on the inside of the torus, then the degree will be 1.  If $p$ is on the outside of the torus, then the degree will be 0.

However, I'm not sure how to get a degree 3 map.

Please help!

Comment: Do you know a degree 3 map from the sphere to itself?

Answer (score 0):

It's a general fact that the degree of a composition is the product of the degrees. Since you have already found a degree $1$ map $f:T^2 \to S^2$, if you can find a map $g:S^2 \to S^2$ of degree $3$, the map $g\circ f:T^2 \to S^2$ will have degree $3$.

Try to find such a $g$ yourself, but I describe one in the spoiler block.

> Take the map which wraps the sphere around itself $3$ times, except at the north and south poles. In [standard spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), $g(\theta,\phi)=(3 \theta,\phi)$.

Comment: And we know $g$ has degree 3, since every map from $S^n\longrightarrow S^n$ has a degree that measures how many times the sphere is wrapped around itself.  Is that correct? So for our example $n=2$ and we can have $g$ be a map that wraps $S^2$ around $S^2$ three times.

Comment: That's right. I'm not sure exactly what your definition of degree is, but if you're using, say, the Guillemin and Pollack definition, then you can simply count preimage points of a regular value (with sign according to orientation).